# Simple Definition of CapEx and OpEx for Software Development

Tags: accounting

I work as a software developer in the UK for a company headquartered in Canada (not sure if the regulations vary from country to country) and I have to log my time for any work I do as either "CapEx" or "OpEx".

Operating Expenses (OpEx) are the costs of running a business day to day. Capital Expenses (CapEx) are long term investments whose benefits continues over a long period.

While there are some simple cases like: * New feature is CapEx * Triaging the dev support queue is OpEx

I'm confused about how to log my time and some of the rules don't fully make sense to me e.g. bug fix is always OpEx (even before the software is made available to the end user?)

Is there a simple definition of whether my work is CapEx or OpEx that works for all cases?

Can a bug fix ever be CapEx?
Is DevOps code to automate deployment or tests for software OpEx?
Is work to implement nonfunctional requirements like performance or backups for software CapEx or OpEx?
Please cite sources in your answers!

Comment: Different accounting regimes have different answers and the answer is only slightly better than arbitrary. For example, the answer would be different under GAAP financial accounting in the U.S. and in federal tax accounting in the U.S. The general rule for GAAP accounting would tend to be that writing a program is CapEx and helping people without changing the program would be OpEx but you aptly point out gray areas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about technical accounting standards and practice, these are not legal issues

Comment: Indeed, lines are quite blurry and I would say context is the king. In case the software is for sale -- bugfix for an unreleased feature is Capex because it is not on the market yet. Bugfix for a product that is on the market is Opex.

Regarding the time tracking aspect, I believe it is a waste of time. There are tools that do it for you https://www.qntify.co/software-capex with better results.